# Propositional Logic Puzzle - Enderton

Tags: propositional-calculus, solution-verification

This is a question from Enderton.

> You are in a land inhabited by people who either always tell the truth
>   or always tell falsehoods. You come to a fork in the road and you need
>   to know which fork leads to the capital. There is a native nearby but
>   he has time only to reply to one yes-or-no question. What would you
>   ask him to learn which way to take?

This is what I came up with and would be grateful if someone could verify if it's right and maybe provide alternate/better solutions.

I would ask him "Is the statement: '*You are a truth-teller **if and only if** the road to your left leads to the capital'*, true ?"

***Yes***

If the bloke is a truth-teller then he points to the right road. If he is a liar then he lied about the statement too. So the statement is false. Then the two sub-statements must have opposite truth values. The first is false since he is a liar. So the road to his left does lead to the capital.

***No***

If the bloke is a truth-teller then the road does not lead to the capital. If he is a liar then he lied about the statement too. So the incorporated statement is actually true. But then it follows the road does not lead to the capital.

So a Yes answer means the pointed road is the correct one and a No answer means I should take the other one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution appears to work. A somewhat simpler question would be "If I asked you which road leads to the capital, would you have answered that it was the left road?". Yes means it is to the left, no means to the right.

Comment: I'm sorry but I miss something. If he is a liar, and replies "yes" to your question, then would you still choose to go to the left?

Comment: @1123581321 Indeed, since that answer meant that he would have answered the question "which road leads to the capital?" with "the right road", which, him being a liar, means the road to the capital is actually the left road. Just the usual trick of forcing a doubling of the (potential) negation.